# How to save the audio files in the gallary?

Tags: whatsapp, music

I want to save the audio files which i recieved through watsapp in the gallary. Plzz help.i tried looking in the Media.but there was no option to save it.please tell me the way.it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in current WP 8.1 OS and Whatsapp version.